# Distinguish Unit Test Traits or Test Properties with Overlapping Values

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

From what I understand, in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 and later, unit test [Traits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx) allow me to set arbitrary key and value pairs on my tests. I've got that working, but it appears there's either a limitation in the query syntax or I'm just missing something. (In C# it looks like Traits can be specified with the `TestProperty` method attribute. I also see this problem with the `Traits` collection on the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase` class when writing a custom unit test adapter.)

Say I have one trait for `Priority`, and it has values in the set `{1, 2, 3}`. If I define another Trait or `MyID` that is also numeric, and 2 is a valid ID, how would I set up a query in Test Explorer to find all priority 2 tests without also picking up the test with ID 2? My understanding of the syntax is for the union of those tests that have a Priority and a value of 2 is this, but this seems like it would cause a clash

```
Trait:"Priority" Trait:"2"
```

I was hoping for a syntax like the following, which would take into account the difference between Trait keys and values:

```
Trait:"Priority=2"
```

Is there a way to do that? I have tens of thousands of tests with up to 20 potential traits of interest, so if I can't do that, I'll have to define globally unique values like `{P1, P2, P3}` for my possible priorities, and likewise for all the other traits. I'm writing a custom unit test framework, so I have the flexibility to do that if it's the only way, but it seems like I shouldn't have to.

Thank you.

Edit: Here's an adaptation of the [C# sample unit test project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243176.aspx) BankTest that shows clashing TestProperty values:

```c#
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using BankAccountNS;

namespace BankTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BankAccountTests
    {
        // unit test code
        [TestMethod]
        [TestProperty("TestID", "1")]
        [TestProperty("Priority", "2")]
        public void Debit_WithValidAmount_UpdatesBalance()
        {
            // arrange
            double beginningBalance = 11.99;
            double debitAmount = 4.55;
            double expected = 7.44;
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", beginningBalance);

            // act
            account.Debit(debitAmount);

            // assert
            double actual = account.Balance;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, 0.001, "Account not debited correctly");
        }

        //unit test method
        [TestMethod]
        [TestProperty("TestID", "2")]
        [TestProperty("Priority", "1")]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
        public void Debit_WhenAmountIsLessThanZero_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRange()
        {
            // arrange
            double beginningBalance = 11.99;
            double debitAmount = -100.00;
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", beginningBalance);

            // act
            account.Debit(debitAmount);

            // assert is handled by ExpectedException
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [TestProperty("TestID", "3")]
        [TestProperty("Priority", "0")]
        public void Debit_WhenAmountIsGreaterThanBalance_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRange()
        {
            // arrange
            double beginningBalance = 11.99;
            double debitAmount = 20.0;
            BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Mr. Bryan Walton", beginningBalance);

            // act
            try
            {
                account.Debit(debitAmount);
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
            {
                // assert
                StringAssert.Contains(e.Message, BankAccount. DebitAmountExceedsBalanceMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the test explorer if you use the filter `Trait:"TestID" Trait:"2"`, it matches both Priority=2 and TestID =2.

Comment: Actually, naming a Trait `Priority` is a bad idea, as you'll find out if you run these, but that's a separate issue.